# Open pop ups in new windows

Tags: javascript, asp.net, popup

I have some pop ups in my website, and I want to open the next pop up in a new window. However, it currently opens in the same window. How can I fix this?

```
function pop_up(url) {
    newwindow = window.open(url, 'name', 'height=517,width=885,scrollbars=yes,
        toolbar=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,location=no,directories=no,status=no,
        titlebar=no,left=400,top=120');

    if (window.focus) { newwindow.focus() }
        return false;
}

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "popup", 
    "pop_up('" + "PopUpEmailing.aspx" + "');", true);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the name of the window from "name" to "_blank".  Change

```
newwindow = window.open(url, 'name', 'height=517,width=885,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,location=no,directories=no,status=no,titlebar=no,left=400,top=120');
```

to

```
newwindow = window.open(url, '_blank', 'height=517,width=885,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,location=no,directories=no,status=no,titlebar=no,left=400,top=120');
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a different window name for each popup.

```
var windowCount = 0;
function pop_up(url) {
     newwindow = window.open(url, 'name' + windowCount++, 'height=517,width=885,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,location=no,directories=no,status=no,titlebar=no,left=400,top=120');
     if (window.focus) { newwindow.focus() }
     return false;


   }
```

Make sure you keep the window names valid identifiers (start with letter or underscore, no embedded spaces) or else IE will get upset.

(Using "_blank" for the name is simpler, if you don't care what the names are.)